# ASCII Expansion

Tags: code-golf, string

## Introduction

Every number can be represented as ASCII. For example, \$0\$ comes in ASCII is \$48\$, \$1\$ is \$49\$, and so on. Using this method of translating numbers to other numbers, it is possible to infinitely expand a number, by replacing all its digits with their ASCII values and doing the same for the result. For example, if you started with \$0\$, you would expand to \$48\$, then to \$5256\$, and so on.

## Challenge

- You will be given a single digit and a number as input. You can assume the digit will be in the range \$0-9\$, or \$48-57\$ in ASCII. You can assume the digit will always be of length 1, and will be a string. The number will always be a positive integer, greater than -1. If it is 0, you do not expand at all. Other than that, there are no guarantees about its value. If, and only if your language has no method of input, you may store the input in two variables or in a list.
- You must output the ASCII expansion of the digit if you expand it \$n\$ times, n being the number that was the input. If your language has no method of output, you may store it in a variable.

## Example I/O

- `Digit = 0, N = 3`

  `Output = 53505354`
- `Digit = 2, N = 2`

  `Output = 5348`
- `Digit = 5, N = 0`

  `Output = 5`

## Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer (in bytes) wins!

Comment: may we take the digit as a string?

Comment: @attinat "You can assume the digit will always be of length 1, and will be a string." Am I reading that wrong?

Comment: @HiddenBabel My own reading ability is the one that's questionable, apparently

Comment: in that case, what about the inverse - may we output or take input as numbers, rather than strings?

Comment: _If, and only if your language has no method of input, you may store the input in two variables or in a list._ What does that mean? And why not just rely on [our default I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/58563)?

Comment: BTW: Apart from that, this is a nicely written first challenge. :-)

Comment: Are only full programs allowed or is function acceptable too?

Comment: @val Functions are acceptable.

Comment: @attinat - the types of input are in the question, like HiddenBabel said.

Answer (score 11):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 28 bytes

```perl6
{($^a,*.ords.join...*)[$^b]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WkMlLlFHSy@/KKVYLys/M09PT09LM1olLim29n9xYqVCmoKBjrE1F4RppGMEY5rqGFj/BwA)

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                          }  # Anonymous codeblock
 (               ...*)[$^b]   # Index into an infinite list
  $^a,                        # Starting from the given number
      *                       # Where each element is
       .ords.join             # The ordinal values joined
```

Comment: (As an aside, Perl 6 is now officially called Raku)

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
FÇJ
```

Takes `N` as first input and the digit as second.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f7XC71///xlwGAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/s5umi5Gd7eL9CYl6KQkpmemaJrZK9p4u9ksKjtkkKSvbF/90Ot3v9r9X5b8xlwGUEhAZcpgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
F    # Loop the (implicit) first input (N) amount of times
 Ç   #  Convert the characters in the string at the top of the stack to its unicode values
     #  (which will take the second input implicitly in the first iteration)
  J  #  Join these unicode integers together to a single string
     # (after the loop, the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,n:f(`ord(s[0])`,n-1)+f(s[1:],n)if n*s else s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcfBCsMgDADQe78i5KRdBurYReiXjEI7aqjgUmkcY1/v9m6vftt@SOidp7K@ntsKShLZLMe5GX242S4kV28v/J@PM4nNDDIqpKIJtH/2XBL4WM8sDdiMWeq7GWs7OqTbgAEpDHhHcj8)

---

**56 bytes**

```python
lambda s,n:eval("''.join(`ord(c)`for c in"*n+" s"+")"*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBDoIwEAXQPaeY/A0daAzWuCHhJi6oQENNnTalajx99a1e@pY9iqluutVgn/fV0qFl3N42KLTt6RG9qDnmVS08u5hpIS/opAcd6MH/cv3sPmx0HlP2Usipzkt6FcVcMUBfGhho0@AKPfwA)

Generates and evaluates monstrosities like:

```python
''.join(`ord(c)`for c in''.join(`ord(c)`for c in''.join(`ord(c)`for c in s)))
```

---

**56 bytes**

```python
f=lambda s,n:s*0**n or''.join(`ord(c)`for c in f(s,n-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBDoMgEEDRvaeYzEYgtEGabky8i1ZLHKMzBDGmp6ds//vxl1dhX0oY9un4LBOclvvTOGMYJLXtcxNiNUpa1KzHIAlmIIag6vfotC73SvsXuj4m4ly7IY5XVlXQoX016NH6Bt9o3R8)

Comment: `and...or` saves a byte [TIO](https://tio.run/##DcpBCsMgEADAe16x7MlNt6CWXoS8pARisRIhXUUtpa@3OQ5M@fU9ix0jLod/P4OHxuJkbuAlQFRbrkG1h15pY7kausRTxq0slCu08d3T8QLjSk3Szz8nKZ@uiAZq5NuEFtlOeEfWfw)

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
{ṫạc}ⁱ⁾
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wv/rhztUPdy1Mrn3UuPFR477//6MVog10jGN1oo10jICkqY5BbCwA)

```
{   }ⁱ     Repeat
 ṫ         stringifying,
  ạ        converting to a list of codepoints,
   c       and concatenating
      ⁾    a number of times equal to the last element of the input.
```

Comment: Huh, not sure I've ever had one of my answers downvoted before.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
ṾOVƊ¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzn3@Yce6Di38//@/wX9jAA)

-2 bytes after a friend helped me figure out what's wrong with `O`

For some reason, to run all test cases with a footer, an extra byte is required for the explicit `⁹` nilad: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzn3@Yce6HjXuPLTw/@Hlx@Y@aloT@f9/dLSBjnGsTrSRjhGQNNUxiI0FAA)

```
Ṿ        Stringify the input
 O       and convert each character to a codepoint,
  V      then concatenate them and eval the result,
   Ɗ¡    repeated a number of times equal to the right argument.
```

Comment: Nice.  Don't know Jelly, but does it help at all that you can take the input as a string?  I was wondering if you could somehow avoid the first step?

Comment: `V` turns it back into an integer anyhow, so the best I could do would probably just be to [change the order of things](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98/7OHOfce6Di38//@/koHSf2MA), since using `V` to stringify and then concatenate the strings all in one byte seems like it ought to be optimal, even though it does end up with an integer.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>14</s></sup> 13 bytes

```
[:,":@u:~"+&3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o610lKwcSq3qlLTVjP9rcqUmZ@QrGCukKagbqEM4RiCOEZRjAOKYqv8HAA)

#### How it works

The "bind" operator `&` is commonly used to bind a constant to a dyad, so that it can be used as a monad. However, [the same form can be used as a dyad](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/ampm#dyadic): `x n&v y` (where `n` is a noun and `v` is a dyadic verb) or `x v&n y` applies monadic `n&v` or `v&n` to `y` **repeatedly `x` times**. Using this feature, we can design the target function like this:

```
x some_constant&some_dyad y
run `some_constant some_dyad y` x times
... or ...
x some_dyad&some_constant y
run `y some_dyad some_constant` x times
```

In this case, there is an obvious choice for the `some_constant`, which is `3` for `3 u: y`.

And here goes the full explanation:

```
[:,":@u:~"+&3
           &   Apply this function x times...
      u:~   3  Convert chars of y to ASCII values (3 u:)
   ":@   "+    Convert each number back to string
[:,            Flatten the array to get a single string
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 30 bytes

```ruby
->s,n{n.times{s=s.bytes*''};s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9euWCevOk@vJDM3tbi62LZYL6myJLVYS1291rq49n9BaUmxQlq0uoG6joJxLBeMawTkGiG4pkCuQex/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>43</s>  40 bytes

*Thanks to @tsh for reminding me that I didn't use currying this time :p (-3 bytes)*

Takes input as `(N)(digit)`.

```javascript
n=>g=k=>n--?g(k.replace(/./g,c=>c^48)):k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcpNCsMgEEDhfU8RspqB@kOiEAKamxRkaqRVNCSl1zduWmgXb/W9p3u7g/bH9mK53H1dTc3GBhONzYwtASLf/ZYceRBchCsZSzc1Ic6xUslHSZ6nEmCFEaGXPWInRKdHLVvq8rsMbRm@i5r@WDbWH64n)

#### How?

This is a simple recursive function. The only trick in there is `c^48`. Because `c` is a string, we need to coerce it to an integer. We could do `+c+48`, but that would be 1 byte longer. Using a bitwise XOR is safe here, as \$48\$ is \$110000_2\$ and `c` is less than \$10000_2\$.

Comment: I believe `n=>g=k=>n--?g(k.replace(/./g,c=>c^48)):k` is valid.

Answer (score 4):

## C# (.NET Core), <s>174</s> 147 bytes

```
class Z{static void Main(string[] a){for(int n=int.Parse(a[1]);n-->0;){var x="";foreach(char c in a[0])x+=c-0;a[0]=x;}System.Console.Write(a[0]);}}
```

Big help from Jo King.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzBCsIwEAV/ZekpQVIiHkO8eBYED4Klh2WNNlATyIZSKfn2mF4ewzA8YkUxuVppRmZ4bpwxe4Il@hdc0QfBOfnwGUZAub1jEj5kCLZtf8PETuBwHKUJSp21kduCCVbbdaalDmkSNDVD4APgoEe5HiwpbXa2qyn3H2f37S8xcJxd/0g@748tNKXUWnU9/QE)

## Ungolfed

```
class Z
{
   static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        int n = int.Parse(a[1]);
        for (; n-- > 0;)
        {
            var x = "";
            foreach (char c in a[0])
                x += c - 0; //c-0 gets converted to int, and then the int is 
                                   //automatically converted to a string
            a[0]=x;
        }
        System.Console.Write(a[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoKing I thought of that first and somehow thought it was longer. But after all the substring business and calc'ing `p` that failed. Thanks!

Comment: `foreach(char c in a[0])` -> `foreach(var c in a[0])`, -1  byte

Comment: Also, get rid of extra space in `Main(string[] a)`

Comment: Move the `a[0]=x` part into the top part of the for-loop, like this: `for(int n=int.Parse(a[1]);n-->0;a[0]=x)`

Comment: With `using System.Linq;` the inner part of the loop can be reduced to: `a[0]=string.Concat(a[0].Select(c=>c-0));`, -6 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>63</s> 57 bytes

```python
f=lambda i,n:n and f(''.join(`ord(c)`for c in i),n-1)or i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIVMnzypPITEvRSFNQ11dLys/M08jIb8oRSNZMyEtv0ghWSEzTyFTUydP11ATyM38X1CUmVcCUmygrmOsyQUE/wE)

-6 bytes due to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan) noting that the input can be a string.

Takes input as single digit string and an integer number of repetitions.

Comment: Take `i` as a string and save six bytes, [TIO](https://tio.run/##Nc7BCsMgDAbgc/cUoRcTcKW6W6HvUlcny1hjES@j9NmdDnYJfz5@QvZPfkaxpYT57ba7d8BaJgEnHgIqNbwiCy4xeVxpCTHBCizApOVqqK5cGnJDNRqrpkvXQBrgqI22@kYVuz2xZOgDHqeG4ySY6@yHWt5cxvTYE9ar8AvyDwHrO0RUvg)

Comment: @Jonathan Allan: Ah! I missed that that was permitted.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>30</s> <s>35</s> 30 bytes

```hs
(!!).iterate(>>=show.fromEnum)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYy9CsIwGEX3PsXX4JBAWkrFpdBsDp0cHNUhhKQNNmnID@LLG1OdDvdezl14eMp1zYZrC8MA0wUwqX5pBOe1jXAAwx3gZEXy/g2KwA2jDtEjoRj1iPY7T4h25FGp/eMaizdDw2AqesG/KOMI94zrmrQ6Ss@jxIyNYdlerfKbOdtkSM4foVY@h9wI574)

+5 then -5 bytes from Jo King clarifying the rules and then working it into pointfree.

My first Haskell golf so I've probably done something horribly wrong. In addition to having misspelled golf, I tried to import `ord` without putting it in my byte count!

```hs
    .                             The composition of
     iterate                      infinitely iterating, starting with the argument,
            (>>=             )    concatenating the results of mapping
                show              finding the string representation of
                    .fromEnum     the codepoint of the argument,
(!!)                              with indexing into the resulting infinite list.
```

Comment: You do have to import Data.char if you want to use `ord`. You can also do this in pointfree style for [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYyxDoMgGIR3n@KXdIAEjbHpYqRbB6cOHdsOhIASAQlimr58KbbTl7vLdxNfZ2lMslw76DoYroBJ8UsMfNAuwgEs94A3J7YQ3qAI3DFqED0SilGLaLvzhGhDnoXaP24xeyNUZxiynvEv8sjgkXBZklpHGXiUeJ2WV63CYi9us6zvSUofoQwf11QJ778) with `fromEnum`

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
VÆ=mc
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=VsY9bWM&input=IjAiCjI)

```
VÆ=mc   V = number of times, U = digit
VÆ      V times do: (Collects each result into an array)
  =mc     Map every digit of U to it's ASCII value, and make that the new U
-h      Take last element
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 22 bytes

```perl
eval's/./ord$&/ge;'x<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@1LDFHvVhfTz@/KEVFTT891Vq9wsbu/38DLmMuIyA05TL4l19QkpmfV/xftwAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 18 bytes

```
([:,3":@u:"0])@[&0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NaKtdIyVrBxKrZQMYjUdotUM/mtypSZn5CsYK6QpqBuoQzhGII4RlGMA4piq/wcA)

From [the J dictionary](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d630n.htm):

> The phrase x f@[&0 y is equivalent to f^:x y , apply the monad f x times to y.

That is, it's a shortcut for power of `^:` applied as many times as the left arg.  Which explains the

```
(  )@[&0
```

part of the code.  Now for what's in the parentheses:

`3 u:]` converts to a unicode code point, but unfortunately has infinite rank, and we want to apply it with 0 rank, hence the added `"0`.  The code point is a number, and we convert it back to a string with format `":`.  Finally, we flatten `,` this list of strings.

Comment: Can you explain your code, I don't know what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: @GalenIvanov Done!

Comment: Thank you! Apparently I can't remember this shortcut to `^:`

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>13</s> 9 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to ngn

```
(,/$`i$)/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P81KQ0dfJSFTRVP/f1q0sbWSgVLsfwA)

Comment: [`(,/$\`i$)/`](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P81KQ0dfJSFTRVP/f1q0sbWSgVLsfwA) works too, with swapped args

Comment: @ngn Thank you! Apparently I didn't know how x and y are applied to this tacit function.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>51</s> 49 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
param($s,$n),1*$n|%{$s=-join($s|% t*y|%{+$_})};$s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0OlWEclT1PHUEslr0a1WqXYVjcrPzMPKFyjqlCiVQkU01aJr9WstVYp/l/LxaWmkqagZKCkYAxhGSkpGEFYpkoKBv8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bracmat](https://github.com/BartJongejan/Bracmat), 63 bytes

```
get':%?a %?n&whl'(!n+-1:~<0:?n&str$vap$((=.asc$!arg).!a):?a)&!a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM5NLPn/Pz21RN1K1T5RQdU@T608I0ddQzFPW9fQqs7GwAooUlxSpFKWWKCioWGrl1icrKKYWJSuqaeYqGlln6ipppj4v6C0BCj430DBGAA)

Comment: Nice 1st answer. One suggestion is to add a [Try It Online](https://tio.run/#bracmat) link in your answer so other users can easily verify your code. It's not required but highly recommended. It can also generate CG&CC posts which is nice.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

```hs
(!!).iterate(show.fromEnum=<<)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAr@iSoFASRbc89orqIGElqYka/b5t5tT5Ms4hZ0ItyCkV0haTdDE8n/cr93T7KTxejaNAr20gisRkQyEVmaEF1tfQAetqGIC1K37b7vSRsdli/AE)

Comment: I don't know Haskell, but there is already [almost identical solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194731/75681)

Comment: @GalenIvanov The linked one does work exactly the same way as this one.

Comment: @GalenIvanov Yup, they're the same. I came up with it independently. Two same  answers isn't surprising here since I think it's the best Haskell can do.

Comment: Yes, it's not surprising to have this when the code is short :)

Comment: I was inspired to write mine entirely by just how perfect an application of the list monad it is, so it definitely makes sense that I'd not be alone in it

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
ＦＮ≔⭆η℅κηη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NTwbG4ODM9TyO4pCgzL903sUAjQ0fBvyglMy8xRyNbU1NHIUPTmisAKFmiAWT9/2/MZfBftywHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes `N` as the first input and the digit as the second input. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ
```

Repeat `N` times...

```
≔⭆η℅κη
```

Map each character to its ordinal and concatenate.

```
η
```

Output the final result.

Sadly `ＦＮ≦℅ηη` doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 55 bytes

```lua
a,N=...for i=1,N do a=a:gsub('.',('').byte)end
print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/UcfPVk9PLy2/SCHT1lDHTyElXyHRNtEqvbg0SUNdT11HQ11dUy@psiRVMzUvhaugKDOvRCNR8////wb/jQE)

Take input as arguments. Explanation is fairly obvious.

## Alternative solution: [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 60 bytes

```lua
a,N=...for i=1,N do a=table.concat{a:byte(1,-1)}end
print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/UcfPVk9PLy2/SCHT1lDHTyElXyHRtiQxKSdVLzk/LzmxpDrRKqmyJFXDUEfXULM2NS@Fq6AoM69EI1Hz////Bv@NAQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 8 bytes

Translation of [Nahuel Fouilleul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70745/nahuel-fouilleul)'s [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194746/43319). Thanks to [Veskah](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78849/veskah) for [pointing it out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52256724#52256724).

```apl
.
⎕UCS⍵M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/1@P61Hf1FDn4Ee9W33//zf4bwwA)

`.` replace any character

`⎕UCS` with the Universal Character Set ordinal of the
`⍵M` Match

This is equivalent to the [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/) expression `'.'⎕R{⍕⎕UCS⍵.Match}⍣⎕⊢⍞`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L@6nvqjvqlB1Y96pwLpUOfgR71b9XwTS5Izah/1LgYKPepa9Kh3HkjxfwUwKOAy4DIGAA)

Comment: Ooh nice! Works with `123456789 10` as well :D

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, 67 bytes

```
i=io.read d=i(1)for _=1,i()do
d=d:gsub(".",string.byte)end
print(d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/0zYzX68oNTFFIcU2U8NQMy2/SCHe1lAnU0MzJZ8rxTbFKr24NElDSU9Jp7ikKDMvXS@psiRVMzUvhasAyC3RSNH8/99AwRgA)

Let `d` be the digit we will transform (always of length 1, so we ask to read 1 character with `io.read(1)`).
If `N > 0`, replace each character by its byte value.
Return the digit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
{CJ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSU3QkNKJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MyUwQSUyMjAlMjImZmxhZ3M9)

##### Explanation

```python
{CJ  # Implicit input
{    # Repeat N times:
 C   #  Get ASCII codes
  J  #  Join into a string
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 41 bytes

```
""<>ToString/@ToCharacterCode@#&~Nest~##&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X0nJxi4kP7ikKDMvXd8hJN85I7EoMbkktcg5PyXVQVmtzi@1uKROWVntfwBQSUm0sq5dmoODcqyavkM1V7WSgZKOca0OkGGkpGMEZpgq6RjUctVy/QcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 16 bytes

```apl
{(∊⍕¨∘⎕UCS)⍣⍵⊢⍺}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v1rjUUfXo96ph1Y86pjxqG9qqHOw5qPexY96tz7qWvSod1ft/7RHbRMe9fYB5Tz9H3U1H1pv/KhtIpAXHOQMJEM8PIP/qxuoK6QpGHOpG4FoIy51UxBtAAA)

Left input is a one-digit string, right input is the number of iteration. Returns the string representation of the result.

#### How it works

```apl
{(∊⍕¨∘⎕UCS)⍣⍵⊢⍺}
{              }  Dyadic dfn, ⍺=digit string, ⍵=iteration
             ⊢⍺   Start with ⍺
 (        )⍣⍵     Repeat ⍵ times...
      ⎕UCS        Convert each char to Unicode codepoint
   ⍕¨∘            Convert each number back to string
  ∊               Enlist (flatten) all chars into one string
```

Comment: [-2 as full program.](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L/Go46uR71TD6141DHjUd/UUOdgzUe9i4GsR12LHvXOAyn6rwAGBVwGXMZcMLYREMLYplwGAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 58 bytes

```php
for([,$a,$b]=$argv;$b--;)$a=strtr($a,range(48,57));echo$a;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BCsIwEEX3OUUoWSQwhdJaFGLxIDHItMRmoW1IoiDi2WNa66we/P/@OOvS8eSsI4RFE2KgHVWE5lMVNBp@WEP9xxaqjFoScp29wcFSvokY6EqCvtcqQz8@8xx6j6/L3fjRcDU9bjcNW1GmvMEVMATW624VJOvLUgqGXYg@ep4zj1NWdwdo90JIM9iZoUzLi4VpcZ4KST4pVan5Ag)

Input digit and number are two command arguments (`$argv`) in same order.

#### Comented

```php
for(
  [,$a,$b]=$argv;  // $a is input digit and $b is number
  $b--;            // loop $b times
)
  $a=              // set $a to
    strtr(         // strtr in array mode, replaces keys with values
      $a,          // replace in $a itself
      range(48,57) // an array with keys 0...9 and values 48...57
    );
echo$a;            // at the end, output $a
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 55 bytes

```cs
a=>b=>{for(;b-->0;a=a.SelectMany(l=>l-0+""));return a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5NS8QwEIbv@RVDTwlNSyt4MU0uywqCenAFz9NsqoHuFNLUD0p@e03Xo6cX3meembFzZWe/3S9ku4cjLRcXsB9dZz8wGHmtPUX5Dxkz6A216bVZhylw1VeVaRRqrE9udDY@If3wUZuxasqiEEIFF5dAgCptin1igEDvoIHcF7wgnacLF4rtq/I98Jk0KkcH7Z5lKWBlAH/eOdNs18/uO/JWwm02Ad6Cj@7Rk@PF2iQJa5vuYL1JhQQvd0vCHIPP3mEii5EP3Nev0@nacSF4HhH5UZbY9gs)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>69</s> 60 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i:i and f(''.join(str(ord(c))for c in n),i-1)or n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcfBCoAgDADQXxle2sCC7Bb0MaZIi9rEvPT1q3d79e2HymJWtivee44gnleGKBkKDsN0Kgs@vaG2jImoaIMELCDkeZzpr1htLB0LuuB8ILIP)

Answer (score 1):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), <s>72</s> 63 bytes

Inspired by @xnor's [Python 2 solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194755/75681)

```
procedure f(d,n)
return(*d*n<1&d)|f(48+!d,n-1)||f(d[2:0],n)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0zOz/v/v6AoPzk1pbQoVSFNI0UnT5OrKLWktChPQytFK8/GUC1FsyZNw8RCWxEop2uoWQPkpUQbWRnEgpSm5qUg6c9NzMzT0ORSAILyosySVI00DSUDJR1jTTQxIyUdI3QxUyUdA02IgQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>62</s> 57 bytes

```
func[d n][loop n[parse d[any[change p: skip(0 + p/1)]]]d]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RccxDoMwDAXQnVN8ZaJiaAB14RhdLQ8RTgAVGSvAwOnTDd72cpTyjUJcpaGkU0cSKNO6bQYlC3mPEAp60TgHnSJswP5brPZoYO/2xczCxfKiBxKcd@ire51D9@zj4Msf)

Explanation:

```
f: func [ d n ] [                  ; a function with 2 parameters
    loop n [                       ; repeat n times
        parse d [                  ; parse the string with the following rules        
            any [                  ; one ore more 
                change p: skip     ; change any string with length 1 (a single digit)
                (0 + p/1)          ; with its representation as a number 48..57 
            ]                       
        ]
    ]
    d                              ; return the altered string
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 21 bytes

```
.+¶

"$+"+`.
$.(*_48*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0/70DYuLiUVbSXtBD0uFT0NrXgTC63//425DAA) Takes `N` as the first input and the digit as the second input. Explanation:

```
.+¶
```

Delete `N` from the output.

```
"$+"+`
```

Repeat `N` times.

```
.
$.(*_48*
```

Replace each digit with its ASCII code.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 88 bytes

Thanks ceilingcat and peter cordez for their contributions.

```c
z(v,n){for(sprintf(o,"%d",v);n--;)for(strcpy(t,o),v=0;t[v];)sprintf(o+v++*2,"%d",t[v]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BCsIwEEX3OUUoVDI2hVq7C56kdBEi1YJOSjIEtPTsMa1VXDi7//48Zkx5MSZ60jQYbq7acdseqrrpFPuFtMH4FEEiTL11wo9uQOqFlVl@zmQAhWWpYK3ImfEhSFqQ4VQpakOn4CsUoSj29VtbKlBzTA2/6wEFsInxNAsI@iY5qjV7o7EXq8N3qYA/GDeYvkzmJ21ns9ynHZvgHCt2fAE)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but `11` is a shorter way to write the integer constant `2^9` aka `2 xor 9`.  Are you sure you don't just want `strcpy` for an implicit-length string instead of a fixed-size 11 byte copy.

Comment: I made a mistake on that ^ operator.  Despite all my years in C every now and again I forget that ^ is not pow().  As for the strcpy, good catch.  Sometimes you get so caught up in old solutions you don't see the best way to write the current one.

Comment: Suggest `v=!strcpy(t,o);` instead of `strcpy(t,o),v=0;`

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 55 bytes

```sh
(($2*#1))&&<<<`$0 $[#1] $[$2-1]``$0 "${1:1}" $2`||<<<$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcoxCsAgDEDR3VMEDaKFgolb8SZFcJLu3aqePU27vOHzn/uSHuKQEJA3RzF6X0ppmABPR1VF3qm2r1gcdNCygNzm1A1JljEdEtBvVhlYzZCMvA)

A port of @xnor's Python 2 solution, it came in just two bytes below [my first solution](https://tio.run/##Hca9CoAgEADg/Z7ioBuUFq3NnyeJhhCl6RJtSnx2i5aP76nnSEJCG@xJQ4k5HjfSAi17YsvepqtgQEFNVGNk7pJnT9sUdtvBOUc8OkBCheunRv1fjRc).
We require quotes around `${1:1}`, otherwise it is removed when empty, turning `$2` into `$1` on the recursive call.

---

If the repeated expansion never grows past 2^63, **53 bytes** with a recursive math function:

```sh
(){s=
for c (${(s::)1})s+=$[#c]
(($2?$0(s,$2-1):$1))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsIwEAXQdeYUH5zFDLaQRtxEiifwBOqiTRvqJoFGN5aePeJbv29Zavyk8H7lVNDeECk@quhWeop5RYDwJsV77XYtx57vh/AkEXZXtlIadm2nnjvVvf7/gBFCxuJExsGROcOSXjBlMnNYMlgEUYZmVKjSlNNcfw)

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 64 bytes

```
dsi[A~48+lrZAr^*lr+srdZ1<P]sP[0srA*lPxlPxlrI3^/li1-dsi0<M]sM0<Mp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b6Bg/D@lODPasc7EQjunKMqxKE4rp0i7uCglytAmILY4INqguMhRKyegAoSKPI3j9HMyDXWBWgxsfGOLfYFkwf//AA)

I wouldn't be surprised if I could golf this down a bit. It's more verbose than anticipated due to handling a lot of edge cases, etc. Put the 'digits' to transform on the stack first, then the number of iterations.

`dsi` stores the number of iterations in `i`. Macro `P` does one iteration of the transformation. `A~` to divide w/ remainder by 10, `48+` to give us ASCII. Variable `r` holds our result. `lrZAr^*` loads this variable for the sake of finding how many digits it currently has. It shifts our ASCII value left (decimal) this many places (48 becomes 4800), then `lr+sr` adds our old value `r` and stores the result back into `r`. Here's tricky situation number one: `dZ1<P` says to keep running `P` as long as our source material is at least one digit. But, we need to do a final run when we hit 1 digit as well.

Macro `M` is our main. `0sr` initializes `r` to 0, and then... the rest of this I'm going to explain a bit out of order. For each iteration, we need to run `P` twice, because of the aforementioned single-digit thing. So, `lPxlPx`. However, this screws us up when our original value is only a single digit. Plus, we often get left with an extra 0 at the right side. `A*` multiplies the original by ten, and `I3^/` at the end divides by a thousand. This is pretty goofy, but it ensures all values work ok. `li1-dsi0<M` keeps running `M` until `i`, our number of iterations, is complete. We can't do `dsMx` as per usual to save & run a macro, because this won't work if our number of iterations is 0. So we test for that, leaving us with the longer `sM0<M`. Finally, we `p`rint.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 54 bytes

One iteration is simply `x.bytes.join()`....

```
Fn.new{|x,y|
for(i in 1..y)x=x.bytes.join()
return x
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCoMwEADAe16xeEpAlkrPufoBX2DLFiLpCuvaJJi@Pep9mCTE7TcLKG0Kvo2MTOmouS/VfFaxAQLDgFhc9hlf5XK4rIGtM0K6C0M2/zaVTemLSYKSvSt8zzHa7tH1T@faCQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
(SCfṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIoU0Nm4bmFIiwiIiwiM1xuMCJd)

```
(     # Input times...
 S    # Stringify
  C   # Charcodes 
   fṅ # Join together (Should just be ṅ, but bugs)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 20 bytes

Takes curried arguments with \$n\$ first and \$digit\$ second, i.e. `F[n][digit]`.

```ruby
:**&(S|:bytes|:join)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWW6y0tNQ0gmuskipLUotrrLLyM_M0IVI31QpKS4oV3KKNY6MNYrmgHKNYIIJxDGKjTWMhqhcsgNAA)

### Explanation

The function `S|:bytes|:join` converts to a string, gets the character codes, then joins them. The `:**` operator applies that function \$n\$ times.

Answer (score 1):

## [Setanta](https://try-setanta.ie/), <s>106</s> 94 bytes

```
gniomh(d,n){le i idir(0,n){i=""le j idir(0,fad(d)){i+=go_teacs(48+go_uimh(d[j]))}d=i}toradh d}
```

Requires `d` to be passed in as a string.

[Try it here!](https://try-setanta.ie/editor/EhEKBlNjcmlwdBCAgICwjuKLCw)

Answer (score 1):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 20 bytes

```
ÀñÓ./½submatch(0)+48
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3DD4Y2HJ@vpH9pbXJqUm1iSnKFhoKltYvH/v8F/YwA)

Input is given as buffer input and an argument.  It runs `:s/./\=submatch(0)+47/g` the arg number of times

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 110 bytes

```rkt
(define(a x n)(if(< n 1)x(a(string->number(string-join(for/list([c(~a x)])(~a(char->integer c)))""))(- n 1))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDBTsMwDL33K8w4YB8i2m2VkJiG@AduiEOWpV22zClJKsaFXy9ux6RJLJL19PTy/GxHbQ42D/decwvxTHBrG8cWNZyACV2DK2Co6IQaU46OW7Xm/rix8UL3wTE2IT56lzK@G/wRL32QIJqdjmrtONvWRjBENJsRoZpayhskB6PVW/oDKopnUErBm005AX4FfsjQSVCGnr1NCRrt/PilKMTy2btoAQP7b@V4WqJnl8HsrDkokbV/kaZ4zUFCS1gQ1Iu6lFre0OcwH/Xl0w2thlK0adJXnwKkvutClGk3rh3XPJ8n3f13VtVVbH1BGkqofwE)

Also, as a bonus, it works with bigger numbers as well! For example: `(a 11 3)` and `(a 123456789 10)` (this gives a number with 9216 digits) are both valid inputs.

---

### Explanation

1. We receive two inputs `x` (the number to expand) and `n` the number of expansions.
2. If `n` is less than 1, we return `x` as is.
3. We iterate through all the digits of `x` by converting `x` to a string. During each iteration, we obtain the string representation of each digit's ASCII value and append it to the list.

   1. `for/list` handle all list appending for us, so all we need to do is return the string at the end of the iteration.
4. Once the list is obtained, we join it to a string without any spaces between all the values.
5. We convert the final string back into a number, pass it to step 1 as the new `x` and pass `n - 1` as the `n` argument.

   1. Repeat steps 1-5 until step 2 is executed.

```rkt
(define (expand-to-ascii x n)
  (if (< n 1)
      x
      (a (string->number
           (string-join
             (for/list ([c (~a x)])
               (~a (char->integer c)))
             ""))
         (- n 1))))
```

*Have an awesome week ahead!*

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 33 bytes

```
[ [ [ >dec ] map-concat ] times ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owc2c0GBPP3crheLUwtLUvOTUYr3UipKixGKF3MSSDL2CxKLi1CIwWyGxuDg_uVihoCi1pKSyoCgzr0TBmourmksBCKoVlAyUFIwVamE8IyUFIwTPVEnBAMirXVpakqZrcVMxWgEE7VJSkxVigYYX6Cbn5yUnlgA5JZm5qcUKsRCFa9MgltoBlSjoQcQWLIDQAA)

- `[ ... ] times` call `[ ... ]` the number of times denoted by the number on top of the stack
- `[ >dec ] map-concat` map over each character in a string, convert it to a string, and flatten

Answer (score 0):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 57 characters

```
* *=@set{d;*}@repeat{*;@set{d;@x{$d}}}$d
x:?=@char-int{?}'
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ echo -n '0 3' | gema '* *=@set{d;*}@repeat{*;@set{d;@x{$d}}}$d;x:?=@char-int{?}'
53505354
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/X0tBy9ahOLWkOsVaq9ahKLUgNbGkWssaKuRQUa2SUltbq5LCVWFlb@uQnJFYpJuZV1JtX/v/v4GCMQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
~!ȯ¡ṁosc→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v07xxPpDCx/ubMwvTn7UNun///9Kpkr/DQA)

Mostly a translation of the Haskell answer, with some combinator stuff thrown in to deal with 1-indexing.

```
 !           Index into
  ȯ¡         the infinite list of iterations of
    ṁ        concat-mapping
      s      show
     o       .
       c     ord
~            starting with the first argument, and with the index being the second argument
        →    incremented.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ceylon, 75

```ceylon
String?x(String d,Integer n)=>loop(d)((s)=>"".join(s*.hash)).skip(n).first;
```

[Try it online!](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=eef93253e35b9bb0564b185ec93826dc)

Here is the long version, which might be more understandable:

```ceylon
"""convert a string of digits (or other characters) into a string of the digits'
   ASCII values, represented themselves as decimal ASCII digits (without any
   separator).
"""
String asciify(String input) {
    // maps each character of the string into its ASCII value (actually unicode, 
    // but that's the same for the relevant range), and this to decimal digits.
    {String*} asciiDecimals = input.map((Character c) => c.integer.string);
    // concatenate all those strings
    return String.sum(asciiDecimals);
}

"""expand a digit (or a string) into its ASCII representation several times."""
String asciiExpand(String digit, Integer times) {
    // infinite (lazy) list of all the expansions
    {String*} allExpansions = loop(digit)(asciify);
    // take the entry `times` steps from the first.
    return allExpansions.getFromFirst(times)
          // If that is null (which can't happen, as we have an infinite list),
          // throw an exception instead.
          else nothing;
}
```

Tricks used to make it shorter:

- one-letter function and variable names
- no comments/doc-strings
- inline the intermediate `{String*}` variables
- use the fat-arrow syntax (`=>`) instead of blocks with just one `return` for the functions
- inline the `asciify` function → then we can use type interference, and don't need to write `String` again for parameter and return type
- use `"".join(...)` instead of `String.sum(...)`. Possibly a bit less efficient, but a slightly shorter (+ next point).
- `join` takes an iterable of *any* objects, not just strings, and will apply `.string` on each element, so we don't need to write down `.string` ourselves.
- use `.hash` instead of `.integer` to get the ASCII/Unicode values – Character's hash code happens to be implemented just the right way.
- replace `s.map((Character c)=>c.hash)` with `s*.hash` (a spread attribute) – the first one is lazy (returns an iterable), the second one is non-lazy (returns a sequence – it's the equivalent for `s.collect(...)`), but this difference  doesn't matter here (as we join the strings shortly after anyways), and the second one is a lot shorter.
- replace `.getFromFirst(n)` with the slightly shorter `.skip(n).first`. (This might get a different result for negative `n`, but those are outside of the specified input range anyways.)
- instead of adding `else nothing` for the return (to convince the compiler that this is not nullable), we can just declare the nullable return type `String?`. It won't happen anyways for valid inputs.
- remove non-essential whitespace

I also thought I found a shorter way of writing this (which works for finite iterables), but it actually doesn't work here, because `loop` returns an infinite iterable, and trying to convert it into a sequence (with `[* ... ]`)will run forever until it runs out of memory:

```ceylon
String?y(String d, Integer n)=>[*loop(d)((s)=>"".join(s*.hash))][n];
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 46 bytes

```arturo
$=>[&do.times:&->join to[:integer]to[:char]<=]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?klsYpE)